# Batch downloading 'offline' Sentinel products

Tags: sentinel, esa

I'm trying to download a 5 year timeseries for Canada of Sentinel 3 SLSTR LST data.
Most of the data is stored 'offline' and has to be restored/ordered. However, it is limiting me to 20 scenes or so, whilst I'm looking to access thousands.

Has anyone found a way to access offline Sentinel files and work around the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try automating this process (quite easily actually) using [eodag](https://eodag.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/api_user_guide/2_providers_products_available.html) python library. The limit you're referring to is only a limit of products per hour (or something like that) and not a limit on the total amount of products which you can download.
With eodag you can set some parameters such as `wait` and `timeout` that will help you achieve your goal. Otherwise, if this is not enough for you, you could [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) product discovery/download combined with eodag.